# Accessing pointer member of the structure using structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have defined integer pointer inside the structure.And i want to use that member pointer using the structure pointer.My code is as shown below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct abc
{
        int *x;
};

int main()
{

        struct abc *p = (struct abc*)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
        p->x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        p->x = 10;
        printf("The value is %d\n",p->x);
        free(p);
}
```

Now i am getting output as per my expectation.But i have got warning message while compiling.The warning messages are:

```
temp.c:14:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
temp.c:15:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
```

I have also tried,

```
*p->x = 10
 printf("The value is %d\n",*p->x);
```

but it is not working.

How to solve this warning?

Comment: `*p->x = 10; printf("The value is %d\n",*p->x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to assign a value to the memory address pointed to by a pointer, you must *dereference* the pointer when used as an *lvalue*. e.g:

```
*p->x = 10;
```

When allocating memory, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`. `malloc` (and `calloc`, etc..) return nothing more than a *memory address* which has no type (or is type `void`). Further, when you use the '`sizeof` *object*' you eliminate the risk of mistake in specifying the type (this becomes more apparent when `typedef`'s are used, etc.). For instance your allocations should simply be:

```
struct abc *p = malloc (sizeof *p);
p->x = malloc (sizeof *p->x);
```

Lastly, in any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. Which is something you fail to do. If you *allocate* it, `free` it when it is no longer needed. E.g.:

```
free (p->x);
free (p);
```

There are many subtle ways to misuse a new block of memory. Using a memory error checker allows you to identify any problems and validate proper use of of the memory you allocate rather than finding out a problem exists through a `segfault`. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice for the memory error checker. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it. E.g.:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/struct_simple
==21079== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21079== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21079== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21079== Command: ./bin/struct_simple
==21079==

 The value is 10

==21079==
==21079== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21079==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21079==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 12 bytes allocated
==21079==
==21079== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21079==
==21079== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21079== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

You want to confirm `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible` and `ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts`

Good luck with your coding in the new year.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing about this is a typo -

```
*p->x= 10               /* <-- missing ;  */
printf("The value is %d\n",*p->x);
```

and also `free(p->x)` before freeing `p` .

[Working example](https://ideone.com/ElpmTK)

Answer (score 0):

Change two lines like this:

```
*p->x = 10;

printf("The value is %d\n",*p->x);
```

it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct abc
{
        int *x;
};

int main()
{

        struct abc *p = (struct abc*)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
        p->x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        int i=10; 
        p->x = &i; //or *p->x = 10; 
        printf("The value is %d\n",*(p->x));
        free(p);
}
```

The problem was that you were assigning the **value 10** to the **pointer**, and it was taking it as an address not as a value and you were trying to print the address using **%d**, so compiler was showing warning.To remove that first you need to derefer to the member of the structure that is an integer pointer, now you need to derefer the integer pointer to assign the value.Or you can take one integer and can store like:

p->x = &i.

To access the pointer that is member of a structure through structure pointer above is the correct way.

Comment: If you storing address of `i` in pointer then no need to allocate memory to `p->x` .

Comment: Let him try it both the ways..

Comment: I am saying when you are doing `p->x=&i` then there is no need of allocating memory to `p->x` . Then depends on OP what he want to do .

Comment: Yeah man , that depends on OP, that's why I told let him try both.For that I've edited my answer also.

Comment: Overwritten in the `p->x = &i;` cause memory leak.

Comment: Yes that's right, then you one shouldn't allocate memory dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
"p->x" can hold only address of an integer as it is a pointer. So instead of value assign address to it.

struct abc
{
        int *x;
};

int main()
{
        int i = 10;
        struct abc *p = (struct abc*)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
        p->x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        p->x = &i;
        printf("The value is %d\n",*p->x);
        free(p);
}
```